# Git repeating parts from previous commits

Tags: git, github, version-control, push

I am experiencing a really weird issue.

I'm working on a website in VSCode and using git as version control (synced with Github).

However, I began noticing that git started marking changes I made in previous commits as changes, asking me to commit them (as if the previous commit was never made?).

For example, say I have the following:

```
Line of Code 1
Line of Code 2
```

And then I commit it, and sync with Github. All should be good.

Later, I add some more lines:

```
Line of Code 1
Line of Code 2
Line of Code 3
Line of Code 4
```

And then I commit it, and sync with Github. All should be good.

Next I go on to work in a completely different file, and commit those changes.

All of a sudden, and this happens completely randomly, it'll mark for example, lines 1 & 2 of the code above as changes that need to be committed. So I do (again).

Anybody have any clue as to what is going on? I am not moving around files, or changing formatting/adding/removing lines of code to the file that could cause it to be marked as a change. I even checked the previous commits and everything seems to be fine. This is really frustrating because I now have a lot of commits that are just re-committing code I had already committed!

Comment: When you sync with github, did there show conflict during sync?

Comment: No, I'm the only one working on this project, so I'm the only person making commits.

Comment: Check if the same commit ID appears on your local history, and in Github

Comment: Can you share your git output/log here? And you can use the command to double check: `git diff` (check the changes between the latest commit and uncommitted changes), `git diff master..master~1` (check changes between latest commit and the parent of latest commit, assume you are working on `master` branch here).

Comment: Git diff shows the changes as if they weren't committed, even though looking at the previous commit shows they were, which is really weird. I recommitted them along with the new changes and the same issue persists, they get committed once again.

Comment: @Adashi and they are all different commit id's

Comment: It's starting to like like Github desktop might be the culprit. I opened it up and noticed that it was showing the changes as uncommitted while VSCode was. I will do some further testing on this theory to confirm it.

Comment: If they are different commit, then there's your problem. Git sees your change as based on another commit, which means that you branched, and this requires rebase, so you actually merge 2 similar commits...
One way to deal with it, is to check out the commit from GitHub before you start new change. In your case, try cherry-picking your new commit on top of the commit from GitHub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an issue related to using the built in git client of VSCode in conjunction with using the GitHub Desktop client.

I was making some commits from the editor, and some from GitHub Desktop.

This caused GitHub to for some reason detect the previous commit as new changes and mark them as needing to be committed.